# XSL Transform from XmlElement to XmlElement

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

```
XmlElement beforeTransform =getXmlElementForTransform();
XmlElement afterTransfrom;

XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load("my.xslt", settings, new XmlUrlResolver());
```

**My Code**

```
xslt.Transform("input.xml","output.xml");
```

**Desired output**

```
xslt.Transform(beforeTransform,afterTransform);
ThirdPartyFunction(afterTransform);
```

There are around 15 overloads of Transform but I am unable to find the one that fits my needs. I know there is no direct XmlElement output using transform (or no input XmlElement object) so I am fine with conversions on inputs and outputs side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the input, you should be able to use [`XmlElement.CreateNavigator()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.createnavigator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  For the output, you can stream through an `XmlWriter` to a `StringWriter`, then read it back in:

```
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer))
            {
                xslt.Transform(beforeTransform.CreateNavigator(), xmlWriter);
            }
            var tempDoc = new XmlDocument();
            tempDoc.LoadXml(writer.ToString());
            afterTransfrom = tempDoc.DocumentElement;
        }
```

Note - not tested beyond compilation.

Incidentally, if you are willing to switch to [Linq-to-XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq(v=vs.110).aspx), you could stream directly from and to `XElement` containers using [`XContainer.CreateReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.createreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`XContainer.CreateWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.createwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: worked perfectly. beyond compilation. Thank you for your quick answer. I implemented it the same day but forgot to up vote and accept answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `XmlElement` object that you want to populate with the result of an `XslCompiledTransform.Transform` you can use `targetNode.CreateNavigator().AppendChild()` to create an `XmlWriter` and use one of the several overloads of `Transform` that write to an `XmlWriter`.